# XML Schema for customizing Office 2010 Ribbon

Tags: vba, ms-office, ribbon, office-2010

I've seen plenty of examples around the internet on how to add a button or group etc. to the Ribbon, but no reference to an XML Schema document that will explain exactly what all my options are for writing the XML for my own custom ribbon tabs and groups. Does anyone have a link for this?

Cheers,
Dave
--Trindaz on Fedang #office-2010-customization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema is [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C2AA691A-8004-46AC-9852-102F1D5BCD18&displaylang=en) and the control identifiers are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3F2FE784-610E-4BF1-8143-41E481993AC6).

Comment: I get an error when I try downloading those, and why would they make you download an .exe anyway?!

Comment: Even though I couldn't get the download to work, other people seem to get access to it fine so I've marked this as the answer.

Comment: Link is broken.  Try this one instead:  http://youpresent.co.uk/microsoft-office-customui-schema/ and Appendix A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui2/daabc2cd-b3f5-4d32-9099-95d705f70f35

Answer (score 6):

It was unclear where Office2010FluentUISchema.exe was installing the schema (after accepting the EULA, the installer flashed up some dialogs so quickly that I was unable to read them) so I observed it via Procmon and found that the schema got installed to a top-level directory called 'Office 2010 Developer Resources'

`C:\Office 2010 Developer Resources\Schemas>md5sum customui14.xsd
e201ed5204216fbe8e84e45c884d2adc *customui14.xsd`

~~ Edit by Martin Rüegg (sorry, I'm not entitled to leave comments yet.)
In case you only need the `customui14.xsd`, then you can just unzip (e.g. with [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org)) the `Office2010FluentUISchema.exe` (twice) and there you are.

Answer (score 0):

http://pschmid.net/office2007/download/customUI.xsd is the closest I got so far